# Kivymd - changing screen from bottom toolbar is not working

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I am trying to put a logic to change screens when the user presses icon in the bottom. I was able to change the screen it using button "Test" but having difficulty from bottom toolbar icon. Below is my code. When i press 2nd icon its printing "Hello" which means code seems working but i feel like i am missing kivy function to connect to different screens.
Please let me know what i am doing wrong.

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivymd.uix.textfield import MDTextField

# Builder String
allLayout  = '''
ScreenManager:
    MainPage:
    #List:
    #History:
    StudentName:
    #Support:
    #FAQ:
    #TermsAndConditions:
    #MyAccount:
    
<Button@MdButton>: 
    font_size: 20
    background_color: 144/235,252/255,144/255,1
    size_hint: 0.32, 0.07

<Ticker@MDTextField>:
    font_size: 20
    hint_text: "Enter student Name"
    icon_right: 'database-search'
    helper_text: "From the list (2nd icon in bottom bar)"
    helper_text_mode: 'on_focus'
    size_hint_x : None
    width:200
<MainPage>:
    name: 'mainpage1'
    NavigationLayout:
        ScreenManager:
            Screen:
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation:'vertical'
                    MDToolbar:
                        title: 'Main Page'
                        elevation: 10
                        right_action_items: [["dots-vertical", lambda x: x]]
                           # on_action_button: app.callback(self.icon)
                    Widget: #if you delete this line... you will spend hours figuring out like before
                    MDBottomAppBar:
                        MDToolbar:
                            icon: "history"
                            text_color: 0,0,0,0
                            icon_size: 0.5                            
                            type: "bottom"
                            mode: "end"
                            left_action_items: [["home", lambda x: x], ["view-list", lambda x: app.listScreen()],  ["watch", lambda x: x], ["help", lambda x: x]]
                           

    Button:
        text:"Class 1"
        pos_hint: {'x': 0.025, 'y':.8}
    Button:
        text:"Class 2"
        pos_hint: {'x': 0.345, 'y':.8}
    Button:
        text:"Class 3"
        pos_hint: {'x': 0.665, 'y':.8}
    Ticker:
        pos_hint: {'x':0.025, 'y': .7}
    Button:
        text:"Test"
        pos_hint: {'x': 0.665, 'y':.6}
        on_release:
            root.manager.current = 'student'
    
<StudentName>:
    name: 'student'
    MDLabel:
        text: "Hi"
'''''

class MainPage(Screen):
    pass
class StudentName(Screen):
    pass

sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(MainPage(name = 'mainpage1'))
sm.add_widget(StudentName(name = 'student'))

class DemoApp(MDApp):
    def listScreen(self):
        
        self.current = StudentName()
        print("Hello")
     #   root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
       
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = 'Lime'
        self.theme_cls.primary_hue = 'A700'
        screen = Screen()
        main_code = Builder.load_string(allLayout)
        screen.add_widget(main_code)
       return screen
DemoApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple strange things going on in your code. One is the code:

```
sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(MainPage(name = 'mainpage1'))
sm.add_widget(StudentName(name = 'student'))
```

which is creating a `ScreenManager` and adding `Screens` to it. But then the created `ScreenManager` (`sm`) is not used These lines can be eliminated.

Another is the `build()` method code:

```
    screen = Screen()
    main_code = Builder.load_string(allLayout)
    screen.add_widget(main_code)
    return screen
```

This code is building an entire display using `Builder.load_string()`. That display has a `ScreenManager` as its root (as defined in the string `allLayout`). And then that `ScreenManager` is added to a `Screen` (`screen.add_widget(main_code)`) and the `Screen` is returned to be the App root window. I suspect that is not what you intended, but it is entirely legal code. I suspect the `build()` method should actually be:

```
def build(self):
    self.theme_cls.primary_palette = 'Lime'
    self.theme_cls.primary_hue = 'A700'
    main_code = Builder.load_string(allLayout)
    return main_code
```

The above code makes the `ScreenManager` the root of the App display.

One final issue is the `listScreen()` method. The line:

```
self.current = StudentName()
```

is creating a new instance of `Student` and assigning that to a variable named `current` in the `DemoApp` class. I suspect you actually want to change `Screens` like this:

```
def listScreen(self):
    self.root.current = 'student'
    print("Hello")
```

This code sets the `current` property of the app root (which is the `ScreenManager`) to the already existing instance of the `StudentName` class.

Comment: thank you! I have updated the code as you recommended and it worked. Also, thank you for taking time to go over the code and explaining what was wrong and which lines I should eliminate. I am very new to Kivy and Python. I really appreciate time you took to explain it, now it make more sense.